# How to disable button button of dynamic div?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular9

I have a FormArray which is populating the fields but the problem is I want to disable all formGroup's button inside the array first and then enable only those who are clicked. Below is my code:

```
<form [formGroup]="updateOptionForm" (submit)="onUpdateOption()">
  <div class="row" formArrayName="optionList">
    <div class="col-5" *ngFor="let option of updateOptionForm.get('optionList')['controls']; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
      <span>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Option</mat-label>
          <input matInput formControlName="option_text">
        </mat-form-field>
      </span>
      <span style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
        <mat-label style="margin-right: 10px;">Answer</mat-label>
        <mat-slide-toggle color="primary" formControlName="answer" (change)="updateAnswer(i)"></mat-slide-toggle>
      </span>
      <span>
        <button type="submit" mat-mini-fab class="done" [disabled]="!i">
          <mat-icon>done</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <button type="button" mat-mini-fab class="cancel" [disabled]="!i"
        (click)="updateOptionForm.reset()">
          <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

But doing this is keeping the last value of `i` as enabled which I understood is because the last value of `i` is taken. Is there any way of doing so ? Like i want to say if the 1st group's button is clicked the other's button will get disabled and clicking the cross button will disabled all the buttons & reset the whole array to the original state during loading.

[image: img]

This is the current scenario as per my code.

Here is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gq5r8c?file=src/app/app.component.html) example for the same.

Comment: Are you considering that !0 is true? Just to check since i can't see the Angular component

Comment: well this is the component's html and what I want is suppose if I click change the value of Option1 then the cross & tick of option 1 will only be enabled but not of the others